# Wordpress Shortcodes Single & Double Quotes Issue

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am adding my shortcodes using custom HTML block in Wordpress Gutenberg editor.

```
[tagged_heading heading_tag="h2" description="Lorem ipsum <span data-attribute='1'></span> sodales dui."]
```

After updating the page all works ok, but after reloading editor window all single quotes, in `data-attribute` for example, changed to double quotes. How I can prevent that?

Comment: The only solution so far is to use different characters instead of single quotes, for example: `{ }` and replace it with single quotes in php e.g. `$formated_string = str_replace(array('{', '}'), "'", $dom_str);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fast-fix solution, which works for me. Single quotes will stay intact if they are placed on the first level and double quotes inside of the single quotes. So just swap them e.g. `[tagged_heading text='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <mark data-tooltip="tooltip"></mark> sodales dui.']`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your shortcode to handle something like this...

```
[tagged_heading heading_tag="h2"]
  Lorem ipsum <span data-attribute="1"></span> sodales dui.
[/tagged_heading]
```

Your PHP code might look like:

```php
add_shortcode( 'tagged_heading', function( $attributes, $content, $tag ) {
    // Merge default attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( [
        'heading_tag' => 'h1'
    ], $attributes ) );

    // Render.
    echo '<' . $heading_tag . '>' . $content . '</' . $heading_tag . '>';
} );
```

Comment: My shortcode is more complex than sample provided. I am already using content for something else.